# Sublime Text 2 Licensing - Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

What happens if you don't licence your Sublime Text 2 software trial? It asks me to license the software and I close that pop up and nothing happens. I don't want to use the software illegally, is it safe to still use it or should I stop using it if I can't pay for it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use ST2 indefinitely without a license. That's just a pop up screen that appears after X number of saves. If you like it and can afford a license, I recommend you buy a license, but it's not required for continued use of the software.

Comment: Yeah, I'd love to buy it, but I don't have the extra money right now. I've heard rumors about sublime Text 3, so I might want to hold off. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Sublime Text 3 beta is out now and you can use it if you are a registered user! The license cost increased to $70 though.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll wait until the full version comes out and buy it. Thanks for the help Rick!